# OSError: [Errno 17] FIle exists when activating environment

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, anaconda, conda

I am installing Conda, and I follow the steps to create an environment, but there is always an error here.

```
shiyu@epsilon-27:~/Downloads$ source activate my_environment
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/conda", line 5, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
activate.main()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/conda/cli/activate.py", line 99, in main
conda.install.symlink_conda(join(binpath, '..'), conda.config.root_dir)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/conda/install.py", line 371, in symlink_conda
os.symlink(root_conda, prefix_conda)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists`
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Try `conda update conda` to make sure you have the latest version of conda.

Comment: shiyu@epsilon-27:~$ conda update conda                                                                     Error: This installation of conda is not initialized. Use 'conda create -n
envname' to create a conda environment and 'source activate envname' to
activate it.

# Note that pip installing conda is not the recommended way for setting up your
# system.  The recommended way for setting up a conda system is by installing
# Miniconda, see: http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/index.html

Comment: I have solved this problem by directly installing miniconda through .sh file... Anyway, thanks!